# TextWrapping in C# DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am creating a datagrid with three columns.  The first two columns are not resizeable, but the third row is.  I need the text in the third row to wrap.  The grid is bound to a database and I am not sure how to enable textwrapping.  Is what I need to do possible?  If so, how do I implement it?  I have tried a few suggestions on this site to no avail.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement yourself a wrap function that runs on the Row_Databound event for example a substring with the maximum value you want.